# Cast failed, invalid lexical value - xs:dateTime

Tags: xslt, saxon, xpath-2.0, stylevision

I am trying to convert a string to date in Altova StyleVision using an Xpath Expression but I am getting this error.

```
Error in XPath 2.0 expression
Line 358, Character 32


(Cast failed, invalid lexical value - xs:dateTime '2017-16-09T12:16:59.407+03:00')
```

My expression is below.

```
format-dateTime(xs:dateTime('2017-16-09T12:16:59.407+03:00'), '[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]')
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an unhelpful error message. Saxon does better:

```
Error on line 1 column 29 of file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/:
  FORG0001: Invalid dateTime value "2017-16-09T12:16:59.407+03:00" (Month is out of range)
```

The problem is that there is no month 16.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really the response is disturbing. Twice you've helped me and I'm really grateful.